# Using OCI8 on PHP, data cannot get fetched

Tags: php, database, oracle, oci8

I've been trying to learn php backend with Oracle DB.
I'm trying to fetch the data from the database with existing table, existing rows. using OCI functions.

The output indicates that there is no rows in the table, even though it exists when I use SQL* plus. Here is the code I've been trying to do. **(Used OCI documentaion)**

```
// Connects to the XE service (i.e. database) on the "localhost" machine
$conn = oci_connect('admin', 'admin', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
else
    echo "connected!";

    $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * from emp');
    oci_execute($stid);
    
    $nrows = oci_fetch_all($stid, $res);
    
    echo "$nrows rows fetched<br>\n";
    var_dump($res);

    echo "<table border='1'>\n";
    foreach ($res as $col) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach ($col as $item) {
            echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "") . "</td>\n";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
```

The output of `echo "$nrows rows fetched<br>\n";` is 0 rows fecthed.

Like I said.. Data exist in database using SQL* plus

Comment: If you inserted data in SQL*Plus then you need to execute a COMMIT statement immediately after you insert the values.  This stores the data in the DB for other people (i.e your PHP application) to see.  Without the COMMIT, only the connection that did the insert will see the data.

Comment: If you're just starting with OCI8, the back half of [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf) may be useful to you.